# alternate php redirection method that works with output preceding it

Tags: php, url, redirect, header

so apparently if you do this:

```
<?php
echo 'something';
header("Location: http://something/");
?>
```

it will not work because there is an output preceding the header...

is there any other alternative php redirection method that works straight from php without installing anything and in which it will still work even if there's an output preceding it so that I don't have to worry about making sure that there is no output before, etc...

Comment: Structure your code sensibly. You're looking for a fix for being lazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not, unless you do something in javascript or html tags in the page that you output itself

if preceding output is a problem 
you can also use output buffering, see ob_start, ob_get 
to get around that

Answer (score 1):

There is no other way to do a php redirect, but you can fool it to still work even with code prior. You would buffer the content and only output it if there is no redirect or reaches the end of the script. Note: this may be resource heavy in some cases.

```
ob_start()
....CONTENT...
ob_end_flush();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no ways in PHP except using `header()`... before output is sent (headers be already sent)...

You can either use meta refresh in HTML that is set at zero seconds, or javascript.

But I wouldn't recommend javascript as some will have it disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh#Examples) tag.

Comment: @kamikaze_pilot, I assumed that if you already output something through PHP, at least some of that included some HTML :)

Answer (score 0):

You understand why this is impossible, right?

As soon as you echo "something" you have sent content to the client, and as part of that client headers were already sent. You can't retroactively modify headers you already sent, and you can't make two responses to one HTTP request.

`ob_start()` and `ob_end_flush()` will buffer the output instead of sending it to the client, which will allow you to get around this problem, BUT
a better solution would be to:

*separate your logic code from your template so that you don't write anything to the screen until you already know you aren't going to redirect.*